# How can a field be efficiently added to a Dataset?

Tags: dataset, associations

Let's use the example `Dataset`:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

And data for a new field `"d"` that I'd like to add:

```
d = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
```

I can add the field by completely unpackaging and repackaging the data:

```
Dataset[Map[Association,Transpose[Append[Transpose[Normal[Normal[dataset]]], Thread["d"->d]]]]]
```

There must be a simpler way! I would like to do this routinely and with large datasets, so I'm looking for something more compact and potentially much more efficient. What am I missing?

Comment: Related: [how-can-i-add-a-column-into-a-existing-dataset](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51472/how-can-i-add-a-column-into-a-existing-dataset).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, that is helpful, but appears to only apply when the new column is some function of the existing ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this auxiliary function:

```
tr = Transpose[#, AllowedHeads -> All] &;
```

you can do

```
dataset[tr /* Append["d" -> {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}] /*  tr]
```

The formatting of the result won't be as nice as the original, because of type inference limitations, but the result is correct.

Comment: Could you please show how to generalize to `ds=ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]` and, say, we want to add a column with the distance from Earth ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks It's a bit harder. This is what I came up with (used consecutive integers for distances, to make it simple): `ds[tr /* Append["distance" -> 
AssociationThread[Normal@ds[Keys], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]] /* tr]`

Comment: Many thanks, much better than de-/re-constructing the dataset from scratch. Hopefully it won't be too long until this kind of operation is built-in.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Indeed, it looks like this operation must be built-in.

Answer (score 7):

```
dataset[MapThread[Append, {#, "d" -> d // Thread}] &]
```

or

```
dataset[Join[#, "d" -> d // Thread /* Map[Association], 2] &]
```

or

```
Module[{ds = Normal@dataset},
 ds[[All, "d"]] = d;
 Dataset@ds]
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this:

```
Module[{i = 1}, dataset[All, <| #, "d" -> d[[i++]] |> &]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
MapIndexed[Append[#1, "d" -> d[[#2[[1]]]]] &, dataset]
```

or

```
MapIndexed[Insert[#1, "d" -> d[[#2[[1]]]], -1] &, dataset]
```

works

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Off-beat question in the image above, what is meant by 3 levels and 27 elements?

Comment: @user1585715 3 is the max depth (that would be the depth of the list elements in c), and 27 is the number of leaves in the datastructure.

Comment: Sjoerd - Thanks very much! That makes sense.