# How would I programmatically add a row to a Dataset?

Tags: programming, data-structures

I would like to use a Dataset to track the process of a lengthy calculation over a large volume of material.  Dataset appeals to me because of the power of the queries and it also looks like it may offer a simple way to serialize results to a data store.

I have not been able to figure out how to programmatically add rows to an existing Dataset.

If I initialize a Dataset named eMap:

```
          eMap = Dataset[{<|"ModuleId"->0,
                       "SegmentId"->0,
                       "x1"->0, "y1"->0, "z1"->0,
                       "x2"->0, "y2"->0, "z2"->0|>}]
```

How would I programmatically add an additional row with the same columns to eMap so that eMap may be queried?

I have tried Append and AppendTo without success.

```
  eMap = AppendTo[eMap, {<|"ModuleId"->0,
                       "SegmentId"->0,
                       "x1"->0, "y1"->0, "z1"->0,
                       "x2"->0, "y2"->0, "z2"->0|>}]];
```

After the call above, if I issue:

```
eMap[1]
```

I get an error: *Cannot apply Append to an expression of the form {__Association}*.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64789/134).

Comment: b. Thanks most kindly - the referenced approach discusses adding additional columns.  Is it possible to add additional rows (with the same columns)?

Comment: Any suggestions for adding a row and in case it exists already overwrite the existing row?

Answer (score 6):

If the curly braces are left out, this seems to work.

```
 Remove[eMap];
eMap = Dataset[{<|"ModuleId" -> 0, "SegmentId" -> 0, "x1" -> 0, 
     "y1" -> 0, "z1" -> 0, "x2" -> 0, "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>}];
eMap = AppendTo[
   eMap, <|"ModuleId" -> 0, "SegmentId" -> 1, "x1" -> 1, "y1" -> 0, 
    "z1" -> 0, "x2" -> 1, "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>];
```

One quick comment - the article referenced by b.gatessucks is well worth a look.  This could be a basis for a very useful set of metadata management functions that allow developers to do SQL-Like operations similar to Alter Structure commands.

Answer (score 3):

```
Append[eMap // Normal, eMap[1] // Normal] // Dataset
```

> {<|"ModuleId" -> 0, "SegmentId" -> 0, "x1" -> 0, "y1" -> 0, "z1" ->
>   0,
>          "x2" -> 0, "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>, <|"ModuleId" -> 0, 
>         "SegmentId" -> 0, "x1" -> 0, "y1" -> 0, "z1" -> 0, "x2" -> 0, 
>         "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>}

Note: using `eMap[1]` as per your example.

At this point, `Dataset` is not fully integrated with the rest of the language, hence the `Normal` workaround.

Comment: Alan - Thank you.  Would you know what additional items are being done to fully integrate Dataset?

Comment: There's an answer to that question: http://www.wolfram.com/data-science-platform/, I don't see how WRI can launch and expect quick - or any - ramp up in use w/o good Dataset integration.

Comment: I agree that data management would need a brush-up ...

Comment: As of version 10.2 (of July 29th to be exact) something like `AppendTo[ds, 
 Association[{"point" -> pointtobeadded, "value" -> RandomInteger[10]}]]` seems to work

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Join` (in version 12.1):

```
eMap = Dataset[{<|"ModuleId" -> 0, "SegmentId" -> 0, "x1" -> 0, "y1" -> 0, 
    "z1" -> 0, "x2" -> 0, "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>}]

(* Dataset[{<|"ModuleId" -> 0, "SegmentId" -> 0, "x1" -> 0, "y1" -> 0, "z1" -> 0, 
       "x2" -> 0, "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>}] *)

eMap2 = Join[eMap, 
  Dataset@{<|"ModuleId" -> 0, "SegmentId" -> 0, "x1" -> 0, "y1" -> 0, 
     "z1" -> 0, "x2" -> 0, "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>}]

(* Dataset[{<|"ModuleId" -> 0, "SegmentId" -> 0, "x1" -> 0, "y1" -> 0, "z1" -> 0, 
       "x2" -> 0, "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>, <|"ModuleId" -> 0, 
   "SegmentId" -> 0, "x1" -> 0, 
       "y1" -> 0, "z1" -> 0, "x2" -> 0, "y2" -> 0, "z2" -> 0|>}] *)
```