# How would I use Map on a Dataset column?

Tags: functional-style, dataset

I am somewhat new to functional programming. To improve the performance of a package, I would like to re-write a package in a functional style.

I have the following `Dataset`:

```
testPoints = Dataset[{ <|"id"->1, "x"->3.75, "y"->3.75, "z"->1.5 |>,
                       <|"id"->2, "x"->-3.75, "y"->3.75, "z"->1.5 |>,
                       <|"id"->3, "x"->-0.95, "y"->-0.95, "z"->1.5 |>,
                       <|"id"->4, "x"->0.95, "y"->-0.95, "z"->1.5 |>,
                       <|"id"->5, "x"->0.95, "y"->0.95,  "z"->1.17 |>,
                       <|"id"->6, "x"->-0.95, "y"->0.95, "z"->1.17 |>,
                       <|"id"->7, "x"->-2.84, "y"->-2.84, "z"->1.17 |>,
                       <|"id"->8, "x"->2.84, "y"->-2.84, "z"->1.17 |>,
                       <|"id"->9, "x"->4.01, "y"->0, "z"->0.83 |>,
                       <|"id"->10, "x"->0, "y"->4.01, "z"->0.83 |>,
                       <|"id"->11, "x"->-2.67, "y"->0, "z"->0.83 |>,
                       <|"id"->12, "x"->0, "y"->-2.67, "z"->0.83 |>,
                       <|"id"->13, "x"->1.89, "y"->1.89, "z"->0.5 |>,
                       <|"id"->14, "x"->-1.89, "y"->1.89, "z"->0.5 |>,
                       <|"id"->15, "x"->-3.75, "y"->-3.75, "z"->0.5 |>,
                       <|"id"->16, "x"->3.75, "y"->-3.75, "z"->0.5 |>}];
```

I am unclear on how I would specify specific columns in a `Dataset` in a `Map` or `Apply` function.

How would I apply `f[x]`, `g[x,y]` or `h[x,y,z]` to the rows in this `Dataset`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends what you want as result and please don't forget to search this site and look through other posts like this one:

- [How can I add a column into a existing Dataset?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51472/187)

Anyway, let me give you two simple examples:

```
f = <|#, "x2" -> #x^2|> &;
h = <|"Value" -> #x + #y + #z|> &;

Map[f, testPoints]
Map[h, testPoints]
```

and you get

> [image: Mathematica graphics] [image: Mathematica graphics]

Since the above code doesn't seem to work consistently in all releases of version 10, please try this alternative as suggested by [Gordon Coale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19027/gordon-coale)

```
testPoints[All, Append[#, "x2" -> #x^2] &]
```

Comment: halirutan - Thank you very much - that is very useful.  I was trying to use a Map[f, testPoints[All, "x"]]  and similar constructs.

Comment: halirutan - I could not get this to work.  I am getting an error message:

Keys::invrl: The argument Keys[Association[TypeSystem`Struct[{id,TypeSystem`Atom[String],y,z},{TypeSystem`Atom[Integer],TypeSystem`Atom[Real],TypeSystem`Atom[Real],TypeSystem`Atom[Real]}],x2->TypeSystem`Atom[Real]^2]] is not a valid Association or a list of rules. >>


I am using Mathematica 10.0.2.  Are you using the same version?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only 10.1 here. Can you tell me what this gives on your machine `<|#|> &[<|"u" -> x, "v" -> y|>]` or this here `<|"u" -> x, <|"z" -> 1|>|>`? If you cannot get this working, can you please poste a complete example that gives the error to e.g. http://hastebin.com/ and give the link here? Or you ask in the [chat].

Comment: @halirutan your format above works in 10.0.1 is broken in 10.0.2 and works again in 10.1.  I strongly recommend [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51472/how-can-i-add-a-column-into-a-existing-dataset?rq=1) for some useful dataset queries. A similar example that does work in 10.0.2 is this : `testPoints[All, Append[#, "x2" -> #x^2] &]`

Comment: @GordonCoale I have included all your information in my answer. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Quoting directly from the help pages `testPoints[All, {"id" -> e, "x" -> f, "y" -> g, "z" -> h}]` will work on 10.0.2  also its worth restarting your kernel when playing with dataset, occasionally it seems flaky and gives errors that a restart fixes.

Comment: @GordonCoale Yes, it always felt a bit half-baken to me too and this is probably one reason why I haven't used it very often so far.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I tried this in 10.1 and it works without issue.  I have submitted the example to Wolfram as a bug report (but they are most likely already aware of this).