# how I should use `MovingMap` on a `Dataset`?

Tags: dataset, map

I am aware of [How would I use Map on a Dataset column?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81075/how-would-i-use-map-on-a-dataset-column#81076) still I cannot see how I should use `MovingMap` on a `Dataset`.

Even the identity functions does not work!

`MovingMap[# &, dataset[[All, "Eons"]], 1]`

My dataset is constructed like this

```
eons = {
  {{2021, 02, 22}, 95},
  {{2021, 02, 23}, 96},
  {{2021, 02, 24}, 100},
  {{2021, 02, 25}, 105}}
```

```
dataset = 
 Dataset[Map[Association[{"Date" -> #[[1]], "Eons" -> #[[2]]}] &, 
   eons]]
```

I can do things that are mere application of fuctions to a single row, e.g. `Map[<|#, "Sqrt" -> Sqrt[#Eons]|> &, dataset ]`. However using

```
MovingMap[# &, dataset[All, "Eons"], 1]
```

as suggested returns itself as output, which usually means mathematica does not know what to do.

Comment: I believe you want `MovingMap[# &, dataset[All, "Eons"], 1]` - note the single brackets. You will need to give an example of your dataset for more help though :)

Comment: Thanks for the susggestion, this too gives the same trouble as using `Part` or `[[`, mathematica return the input as output ... meaning it did not understand

Comment: Indeed, it looks like MovingMap doesn't like to work directly on Dataset in this way. You can do either `MovingMap[# &, Normal@dataset[All, "Eons"], 1]` or `dataset[MovingMap[(# &), #, 1] &, "Eons"]`.

Comment: From the help of MovingMap:  "The data can be a list of values {Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],\[Ellipsis]}, a list of time-value pairs {{Subscript[t, 1],Subscript[x, 1]},{Subscript[t, 2],Subscript[x, 2]},\[Ellipsis]}, a TimeSeries, EventSeries, or TemporalData.", but not Dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I posted in my comment: it looks like `MovingMap` doesn't like to work directly on Dataset in this way.

There are a few alternatives.

You can use the Dataset-style syntax to apply a function to a column's values:

```
dataset[MovingMap[(# &), #, 1] &, "Eons"]
```

You can do

```
MovingMap[# &, Normal@dataset[All, "Eons"], 1]
```

in order to convert the dataset's values into a simple list using `Normal`.

You can also convert your Dataset into TimeSeries data that MovingMap can operate directly on:

```
dataset = 
 Dataset[Map[
   Association[{"Date" -> DateObject@#[[1]], "Eons" -> #[[2]]}] &, 
   eons]]
ts = TimeSeries@Normal@Values@dataset
MovingMap[# &, ts, 1] (* returns a TimeSeries as well *)
```

Comment: I missed the fact that `dataset[f,"columnName"]` is essentially `Apply` to the column!