# Adding key-value pairs to an association. What are the alternatives?

Tags: programming, associations

Given the following MWE, where:

```
lst = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 2|>};
```

and the problem is that:

```
if the value of a is greater than 3 then "c"-> True must be added to the association.
```

I have the following =working= code

```
Map[If[#[[1]] > 3, var = #; AssociateTo[var, "c" -> True], #] &, lst]
```

which yields:

```
{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, 
<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>, 
<|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>, 
<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 2, "c" -> True|>, 
<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 2, "c" -> True|>}
```

I prefer If-less programming and the var=# looks so unnecessary.

**Is there a more "elegant" solution to this problem?**

Comment: It would appear that you can add keys with at least `Join`, `Append`, `Prepend`, `<|..., key -> val|>`. I guess this was your real question.

Comment: Related: [(51472)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51472/121)

Comment: That's quite an interesting question/answers-set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#` and `If` -less approach:

```
lst /. a : KeyValuePattern["a" -> n_ /; n > 3] :> <|a, "c" -> True|>
```

Comment: So there is an If-less version after all. Beautiful code.

Comment: @niloderoock Is `If`-less a primary metric of success here?

Comment: I have this hypothesis that IF's are red flags for poor program design: "When the IF's come in, the quality of software starts to deteriorate."

Comment: In refactoring code ( i.e. Java ) I aim to remove all IF's which always leads to cleaner design and code with much less LOC.

Comment: Accepted. I didn't even know KeyValuePattern. This function will be of help in a few places of my code.

Comment: @niloderoock Thanks. Yes it is useful and makes code quite readable.

Comment: @niloderoock, be aware KeyValuePattern matches at most one instance per rule. Not sure what the intention of that limit is.

Answer (score 7):

Terse style:

```
<|#, If[#a > 3, "c" -> True, {}]|> & /@ lst
```

> ```
> {
>  <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>,
>  <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>,
>  <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>,
>  <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 2, "c" -> True|>,
>  <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 2, "c" -> True|>
> }
> ```

For what it's worth version 10.1 does not have [`KeyValuePattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValuePattern.html), but this works:

```
lst /. x_ /; x["a"] > 3 :> <|x, "c" -> True|>
```

And just to play with other methods:

```
<|#, DeleteCases[<|"c" -> #a > 3|>, False]|> & /@ lst
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend

```
If[#a > 3, Append[#, "c" -> True], #] & /@ lst
```

if you can tolerate a bit of `If`.

Comment: Yes, me too, too much `If` though.

Comment: @Kuba Well, you gave the `If`less version and there were a few small things to improve in the original that may make the `If` bearable after all.  Consider it an alternative.

Comment: Right. p.s. don't know if better, but shorter: `<|#, "c" -> True|>`

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, I did not know this. Do you know why `Association` is not `Flat`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I'd ask WReach if I'd like to know ;)

Comment: Maybe because it is stronger than Flat. It also flattens `List`'s: `Association[a->1, {b->2, Association[c->3]}]` gives `<|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>`.