# How to change a key's value of association?

Tags: associations

I want to write a pure function to change the key's value of an association, it must return the new association, so it can be mapped to a table of associations.

The AssociateTo can change key's value of an association, but it seems not working. I don't know why, perhaps because it is not a pure function?

[image: AssociateTo]

So if I have a pure function doing the same thing, this job can be done very well.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Use `Append`.  `AssociateTo` is for changing the value of a variable. You have no variables.

Comment: In general case `Merge[Last]`, in even more general case [**102466**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102466/5478), but here, in addition to what Szabolcs said, you can `<|#, "key"->value|>&/@data`

Comment: Thank you. `<|#, "key"->value|>` works well.

Comment: closely related: [74165](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74165/5478), [137455](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137455/5478)