# Sum all columns from a list

Tags: function-construction, dataset

I have a list of column names:

```
list = {"col1", "col2", "col3"}
```

and a dataset `ds`. I want to add a new column to `ds` that contains the sum of the columns listed in `list`. As suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51472/534), I could do:

```
ds[All, <| #, "colnew" -> #col1 + #col2 + #col3 |> &]
```

But I cannot list the column names by hand, because the list may be very large, or I might not know the names of the columns *a priori*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the you want to total *all* columns instead of just those on a select list, then the [suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147348/sum-all-columns-from-a-list/147400#comment395865_147348) given by [@Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) is appropriate:

```
ds[All, <| #, "colnew" -> Total@# |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

If you wish to total only the listed columns, then:

```
ds[All, <| #, "colnew" -> Total[#[[list]]] |> &]
```

For example:

```
list = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};

ds = AssociationThread[list->#]& /@ RandomInteger[10, {4, 3}] // Dataset

ds[All, <| #, "colnew" -> Total[#[[list]]] |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Or, asking for an actual subset of columns:

```
list2 = {"col1", "col2"};

ds[All, <| #, "colnew" -> Total[#[[list2]]] |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: I suppose I missed the point :)

Comment: @Kuba Actually, I just reworded my response to emphasize your suggestion -- to match the title of the post :)

Comment: I don't sure you have read my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148499/21532).But I have read yours many many times,which make me upset sometimes I have to say.I think your solution works just beacuse result by a unexpected behavior derive from *MMA*.Note this [two `f`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G64y4.png) is in different place(one is in the inner of `Association`，but another out of it,and I think it is should in outside).Though they is a same operation.I think the solution is right,I mean that behavoir is expected.

Comment: @yode You are right -- the documentation makes no explicit mention of this syntax.  But it does say that a list of rules will be treated as if the rules has been specified directly.  Associations are treated like lists in many functions, so it would be surprising if `Association` itself did not do that.  I think the syntax is a logical consequence of these principles.  For the first example in your screenshot to work, I would expect `f` to evaluate to a rule, list or association.

Answer (score 3):

You can programmatically generate `<| #, "colnew" -> #col1 + #col2 + #col3 |> &` as follows.

```
list = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};

Tr[Slot /@ list] /. x_ :> (<|#, "colnew" -> x|> &)
```

> ```
> Association[#1, "colnew" -> #col1 + #col2 + #col3] &
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"col1" -> 1, "col2" -> 2|>, <|"col1" -> 3, 
    "col2" -> 4|>, <|"col1" -> 5, "col2" -> 6|>}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ds[All, Append[#, "colnew" -> Total[#]] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]