# Add a column to the left side of a dataset

Tags: dataset

What I am trying to do is to add an id column at the left side of my data set.

This is the data set I am working with. I Have three columns and I want to add a new column on the left side with the column tag ID with the following values: `Id={1,2,3,4,5,6}`.

```
Dataset@
 {
  <|"Team name" -> "Chealse", "GF" -> 23, "GA" -> 12|>,
  <|"Team name" -> "Arsenal", "GF" -> 30, "GA" -> 13|>,
  <|"Team name" -> "Burnley", "GF" -> 33, "GA" -> 15|>,
  <|"Team name" -> "Everton", "GF" -> 53, "GA" -> 11|>,
  <|"Team name" -> "Watford", "GF" -> 45, "GA" -> 9|>,
  <|"Team name" -> "Brighton", "GF" -> 24, "GA" -> 7|>
  }
```

Comment: see [how-can-i-add-a-column-into-a-existing-dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51472/how-can-i-add-a-column-into-a-existing-dataset)

Comment: If your dataset is `ds` then `n = 1; ds = ds[All, Prepend[#, "ID" -> n++] &]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Join[Dataset[Association /@ Thread["ID" -> Id]], ds, 2]
```

[image]

Also

```
MapIndexed[Prepend[#, "ID" -> #2[[1]]] &, ds]
```

[image]

Comment: It worked fine, but I don´t understand the 2 on the `Join` function.

Comment: @LasDes, the third argument of `Join` specifies that the elements at `Level` 2 of the objects in  the first and second argument are to be joined. Try, for example, `Join[{{a}, {b}, {c}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}]` and `Join[{{a}, {b}, {c}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}, 2]`

Comment: I can see now why, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
ds[MapIndexed[<|"ID" -> First@#2, #|> &]]
```

[image]