# Replacing numeric values with a string in a particular list column

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I am trying to replace numeric values in the status column below with the text "Dead" using `ReplacePart` but I'm not getting the desired result. Please help.

YOB         status
1910        1982
1977        ALIVE
1951        2012
1977        ALIVE

```
lis = {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, 1982}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951, 2012}, {1977, "ALIVE"}}
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: `lis /. {yrS_, yrF_?NumericQ} :> {yrS, "DEAD"}`

Comment: To explain @BobHanlon 's beautiful answer, he creates a `RuleDelayed` that would replace something with a replacement. Then defines the something as a list with two elements, the first can be anything, but the second must be a number. All those lists are replaced by their same first element and as a second element the word "DEAD." Beautiful! `Rule` seems to work just as well as `RuleDelayed` for me, so he might explain if the latter has some advantage that I don't see.

Comment: @NicholasG - There is no advantage to either `Rule` or `RuleDelayed` in this case. I just tend to use `RuleDelayed` unless there is a reason not to.

Comment: Thanks Bob and Nasser.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to replace the numeric values in the status column below
> with the text "Dead"

`Position` returns output designed to be used by `ReplacePart`. So you can first use `Position` to find the positions where you want to do the replacement, then use `ReplacePart` on that.

```
lis = {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, 1982}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951, 2012}, {1977, "ALIVE"}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
p = Position[lis[[All, 2]], _?NumericQ]
lis[[All, 2]] = ReplacePart[ lis[[All, 2]], p -> "DEAD"];
MatrixForm[lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, 1982}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951, 2012}, {1977, "ALIVE"}};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceReplace[list, {{a_, _Integer}} :> {a, "DEAD"}]
```

> {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, "DEAD"}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951,
> "DEAD"}, {1977, "ALIVE"}}

**Positional solutions**

Get replacement positions

```
p = MapAt[2 &, {All, 2}] @ SequencePosition[list, {{_, _Integer}}]
```

> {{2, 2}, {4, 2}}

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> "DEAD", p] @ list
```

```
ReplacePart[p :> "DEAD"] @ list
```

```
MapAt["DEAD" &, p] @ list
```

All produce

> {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, "DEAD"}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951,
> "DEAD"}, {1977, "ALIVE"}}

Answer (score 1):

### Motivation

Another approach is to convert your data into an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html). It might involve one or two steps beforehand but in my opinion, it makes for safer and more legible code in the long run.

It has numerous advantages over working on a `List` but the one I find most useful is that I can call a column by its name instead of its index.

For example, your code is more legible with

```
someBigDataAssociation[[All,"EyeColour"]]
```

compared to

```
someBigDataList[[All,42]]
```

It also makes your code more resilient, what if your data changed and "EyeColour" is no longer in column 42?

---

### Helper Functions

First, we define some helper functions to move between associations and tables with headers.

```
(* helper functions *)

convertTableWithHeaderToAssociation[table_List] :=
  Module[
   {
    header = First[table],
    body = Rest[table]
    },
   AssociationThread[header, #] & /@ body
   ];

convertAssociationToTableWithHeader[association_List] :=
  Module[
   {
    header = {First[Keys[association]]},
    body = Values[association]
    },
   header~Join~body
   ];
```

---

### Answer

Convert your data to an `Association`

```
birthAndDeathYear = convertTableWithHeaderToAssociation[lis]
```

> {<|"YOB" -> 1910, "status" -> 1982|>, <|"YOB" -> 1977,
> "status" -> "ALIVE"|>, <|"YOB" -> 1951,
> "status" -> 2012|>, <|"YOB" -> 1977, "status" -> "ALIVE"|>}

Now we redefine the `"status"` column applying our `NumericQ` rule to `#status` *(see Note)*

```
birthAndDeathStatus = <|#, 
    "status" -> If[NumericQ[#status], "DEAD", #status]|> & /@ 
  birthAndDeathYear
```

> {<|"YOB" -> 1910, "status" -> "DEAD"|>, <|"YOB" -> 1977,
> "status" -> "ALIVE"|>, <|"YOB" -> 1951,
> "status" -> "DEAD"|>, <|"YOB" -> 1977, "status" -> "ALIVE"|>}

Depending on what you want to do with this data next, you can :
inspect it with `Dataset` ...

> [image: Dataset]

...or `TableForm`...

> [image: TableForm]

or return it to the original format, perhaps to `Export` it later

```
convertAssociationToTableWithHeader[birthAndDeathYear]
```

> {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, 1982}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951,
> 2012}, {1977, "ALIVE"}}

---

### Note

This makes use of the fact that "Associations keep only the last instance of repeated keys"

for example

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "b" -> "bar"|>
```

> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "bar"|>

For more information on working with `Associations` (and `Dataset`), I found [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51473/60568) from WReach very helpful.

---

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, 1982}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951, 2012}, {1977, "ALIVE"}};
```

---

Using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[list, {a_, _Integer} :> {a, "DEAD"}, {1}]
```

> {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, "DEAD"}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951, "DEAD"}, {1977, "ALIVE"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, 1982}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951, 
    2012}, {1977, "ALIVE"}};

Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], list[[All, 2]] /. _Integer :> "DEAD"}]

list /. {a_, Except["ALIVE" | "status"]} :> {a, "DEAD"}
```

---

```
{{"YOB", "status"}, {1910, "DEAD"}, {1977, "ALIVE"}, {1951, 
  "DEAD"}, {1977, "ALIVE"}}
```