# Multiple append over a Dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations, slot

I have the following association :

```
dat = <|"(1)" -> <|"A" -> -1, "B" -> -1, "C" -> -1|>, 
"a" -> <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> -1, "C" -> -1|>, 
"b" -> <|"A" -> -1, "B" -> 1, "C" -> -1|>, 
"ab" -> <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 1, "C" -> -1|>, 
"c" -> <|"A" -> -1, "B" -> -1, "C" -> 1|>, 
"ac" -> <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> -1, "C" -> 1|>, 
"bc" -> <|"A" -> -1, "B" -> 1, "C" -> 1|>, 
"abc" -> <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 1, "C" -> 1|>|>
```

Which can be transformed into a Dataset as :

```
ds = Dataset@dat
```

I would like to perform multiplications of combinaisons of several columns. The columns which must be multiplied are given by `index` :

```
header = Flatten@DeleteDuplicates@Keys@Values@dat;
index = Select[Subsets[header], Length@# >= 2 &];
(*index = {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "C"}, {"B", "C"}, {"A", "B", "C"}} <- these columns must be multiplied together*)
```

I have found on [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51472/how-can-i-add-a-column-into-a-existing-dataset) a way to achieve that for column A and B (`index[[1]]`) :

```
i = 1;
ds[All, Append[#, StringJoin@index[[i]] -> Times @@ {#A, #B}] &]
```

Now I'd like to apply this on each element of `index`. I've unsuccessfully tried

```
ds[All, Append[#,StringJoin@index[[i]] -> Times @@ Map[Slot, index[[i]]]] &]
```

with the hope that I can then iterate over index...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work well for me:

```
ds[All, 
   Append[#, 
     Map[
       cols |-> StringJoin[cols] -> Times @@ Through[Map[Lookup, cols][#]], 
       index]] &]
```

**UPDATE**: Incorporating @kglr suggestion, the resulting code is:

```
ds[All,
   Append[#, 
     Map[
       cols |-> StringJoin[cols] -> Times @@ Lookup[cols][#], 
       index]] &]
```

Comment: (+1) For a slightly simpler version you can replace `Times @@ Through[Map[Lookup, cols][#]]`  with `Times @@ Lookup[cols][#]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
addColumns[indices_] := <|#, indices /. c : {Except[_List] ..} :> 
   Rule[StringJoin @ c, Times @@ KeyTake[#, c]]|> &

ds[All, addColumns[index]]
```

[image]